# Как ограничить RAM для всех и вся?

Tags: linux, ram, elementary-os, limit

Как ограничить RAM для всех и вся в ОС Linux?

```
elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya => Built on Ubuntu 14.04
```

К примеру, у меня установленно 6гб оперативной памяти, мне необходимо установить лимит, дальше которого не подняться. К примеру, я установил лимит в 4гб, для ОС это должно быть максимальным.

В Windows подобное устанавливается в MSconfig. К сожалению о аналогах в Linux мне ничего не известно.

Comment: а в чём смысл? спрашиваю потому, что вопрос очень похож на [проблему xy](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin если вопрос задан значит в нем есть смысл.

Comment: не спорю. вероятно, я плохо сформулировал. я спрашивал не о смысле вопроса, а о цели, которой вы хотите добиться. просто не использовать часть памяти, конечно, возможно. но я предполагаю, что требуется на самом деле ограничение использования памяти на каждый **процесс**.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin именно что на каждый процес, просто последний сектор памяти поврежден, поэтому нужен лимит что бы он не доходил до этого сектора.

Comment: я дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

если вам на самом деле необходимо ограничить именно программу *linux* в использовании оперативной памяти, то следует передать ей в качестве параметра (при загрузке):

```
mem=желаемый_размер
```

например:

```
mem=4G
```

---

[инструкция по передаче доп. параметров программе *linux*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) на примере дистрибутива *ubuntu*.

---

### обновление в связи с уточнением в комментарии.

> последний сектор памяти поврежден

тогда вам, вероятно, лучше зарезервировать нужный блок памяти. это можно сделать с помощью параметра (при загрузке):

```
memmap=nn[KMG]$ss[KMG]
```

означающего: зарезервировать nn (кило-, мега-, гига-) байт памяти, начиная с адреса ss (кило-, мега-, гига-) байт.

[пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911848/4827341) — исключить использование памяти с 0x18690000 по 0x1869ffff:

```
memmap=64K$0x18690000
```

или

```
memmap=0x10000$0x18690000
```